# Understanding $L^1 \cap L^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I've started learning some functional analysis and I'm struggling to understand the $L^1 \cap L^\infty$ space.
The abstract of the paper https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-42758-4_3 discusses it and defines the norm on this space as

$$ \Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^1 \cap L^\infty} := \max\left( \Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^1}, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^\infty} \right). $$

I don't see how $L^1 \cap L^\infty$ is different from just the $L^1$ space.

My Reasoning:
For $f \in L^1$ we have

$$ \int_\Omega \vert f(x) \vert d\mu(x) < \infty $$

ie. $f$ is absolutely integrable (a.e.).
That implies $\vert f(x)\vert <\infty$ for almost all $x$.
Therefore $f \in L^\infty$.
On a similar line of thought I would have expected $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^1} \geq \Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^\infty}$.
That would suggest to me that $L^1 \subseteq L^\infty$ and then their intersection is just $L^1$.

Could somebody please explain why this is not so (maybe using a counter-example)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Finite almost everywhere doesn't imply essentially bounded. Consider for instance $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ for $0<x<1$, zero elsewhere. This function is in $L^1$ but not $L^\infty$.

Comment: Also $f(x)=1$ is $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ but not $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: And plus, $\|\cdot\|_1\geq\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is *really wrong*. In fact, for every measurable function on a compact interval it is (up to a constant which is the length of the interval) the other way around. (Try it with $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ for example.)

Comment: those examples are great, thank you very much!